# Not able to use custom web font saved in github repo

Tags: html, css, font-face

trying to create a website using a custom font. uploaded .otf file of the font to GitHub, and i cant figure out why CSS command isn't working.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Brandon';
  src: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/segoviaa1/solo-tutoring/master/brandon-grotesque-light-58a8a4b38001d.otf?raw=true") format ("opentype");
}

.Brandon {
  font-family: "Brandon"
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align:center ; font-family:Brandon; color:Green ;font-size:80px">We Are Solo</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've removed the `format ("opentype")` and it worked but I'm not sure why, I'll de a little research.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Brandon';
  src: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/segoviaa1/solo-tutoring/master/brandon-grotesque-light-58a8a4b38001d.otf?raw=true");
}

.Brandon {
  font-family: "Brandon"
}
```

```html
<h1 class="Brandon">We Are Solo</h1>
```

*Edit:* Apparently, the `raw=true` parameter in the request is doing something to the file, if you remove it you can use the `format("opentype")` as the snippet shows bellow, but I'm still not sure what exactly is happening.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Brandon';
  src: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/segoviaa1/solo-tutoring/master/brandon-grotesque-light-58a8a4b38001d.otf") format("opentype");
}

.Brandon {
  font-family: "Brandon"
}
```

```html
<h1 class="Brandon">We Are Solo</h1>
```

*Edit 2:* I don't have more ideias for what could be happening, If anyone has any ideias feel free to edit my answer, add another one or add a commentary.